# Деление по модулю

Tags: php

Читаю *"Zend PHP Certification Study Guide"*. В разделе "*Arithmetic Operations*" вижу такое замечание:

```
Keep in mind that the modulus operation works a bit different from the typical mathematical operation because it returns a signed value rather than an absolute one.
```

Поясните, пожалуйста, что такое **signed value** и **absolute value**, и в чем именно специфика деления по модулю в PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

signed value может быть по модулю вдвое меньше absolute. В общем, если не собираетесь связываться с bitwise, не парьтесь. А если собираетесь, используйте только их.